# Wordpress Plugins to hide complete blog with blog title

Tags: wordpress, blogs

I am using "user specific content" plugin, using this I can hide particular blog content for specific user role. But I want to hide content including post title. What I meant is only the specific user can see the post content & post title. And post title along with post content should be hide for blocked user. I know there is some custom coding for it that I have to do in plugins file. 
 But I don't have any idea how to do coding for it and where to place the code.
Can anyone give me suggestion for code and for where I have to place this custom code?

Comment: I think you have to create custom role

Comment: admin side or front end? you can simply hide using css.

add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');

function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    body, td, textarea, input, select {
      font-family: "Lucida Grande";
      font-size: 12px;
    } 
  </style>';
}

Comment: $user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'author', (array) $user->roles ) ) {
    echo the css here..
}

Comment: no this is wrong way

Comment: front end side.